# Use a command inside a \url or \href or \nolinkurl

Tags: formatting, hyperref

I'm trying to typeset a `\nolink` URL whose a part is formatted differently (eg. in bold, or enclosed by angle brackets).

In the following example, I would like to format `<param1>` in bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This is a "parametrized" URL: \nolinkurl{https://example.com/<param1>/test.html}.
\end{document}
```

It fails when I try to use `\textbf` inside the `\nolinkurl`.
Is there a clean way to perform such kind of thing?

Edit: I would like the hyphenation to be preserved. For example, the appearance of these two lines should be the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\begin{document}
xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \url{example/}\textbf{ccc}\url{bbb}

xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \url{example/cccbbb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is imho no "clean" way. Internally \url/\nolinkurl uses math mode and the "hyphenation points" are handled with math penalties. There is no good way to combine this with text formatting.

Answer (score 2):

`\nolinkurl` doesn't bother if the argument is not a valid URL:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Parametrized URL:
\nolinkurl{https://example.com/}\textbf{<param1>}\nolinkurl{/test.html}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But won't it break the hyphenation of URLs as implemented by `\nolinkurl`?

Comment: @JohnDoe Why should it? It actually doesn't.

Comment: Let's say that I have the following URL: http://xxx.com/a<param>b/.
Under normal circumstances, the URL shouldn't break between `a` and  `<param>`. However, when I use your solution, it breaks. Is there a way to solve such a problem?
If I use a `\url`, as stated in the title, I won't be able to click on the `<param>`. How can I solve that?

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, I can't reproduce; with `\nolinkurl{https://example.com/a}\textbf{<param1>}\nolinkurl{b/test.html}` I'm not able to get a break between `a` and `<param1>`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of a working example and the bad explanation. I've updated my question with an example and I can provide the PDF output if needed.

Comment: @JohnDoe What does the example have to do with the question? And with my answer? You asked for `\nolinkurl`.

Comment: When I use your solution, the URL doesn't break at all between the "/" and the beginning of the "ccc" param.
When everything is inside a `\url`, the URL breaks between the "/" and the "ccc" param.
I would like the breaks to happen in the same place with and without formatted params.

Comment: @JohnDoe `\allowbreak\textbf{ccc}`

Comment: Should I ask another question for the `\url` version where the param is not clickable?

Comment: @JohnDoe You should ask clear questions. I'm going to remove my answer.